# Passport Mail Return

Tags: uk

I sent my passport in person by mail by UPS, but forget to pay for return. I then purchased just envelop with my name and sent it by mail to the UKVI scanning Hub. What should I do?
Will the passport be returned by this way?
Thank you

Comment: What's your country of citizenship? The Visa application asks for, among other things, your phone number, so I would expect that they'll eventually call you asking for you to snail mail them a check.

Comment: In what country did you apply for the UK visa?

Comment: @neubert Considering that many (most?) countries don't use checks and haven't for decades, that seems only likely if OP is in one of those last vestiges of the early 20th century that still survives.

Comment: Ask the embassy/the visa office.  They will tell you what to do (and how they could help you). For sure they do not want to make public that they could make some exceptions if the error were genuine. Worst case: you should collect it in person.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.